# Formatting Columns and rows with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a modal that I am having trouble formatting. I am a novice front end coder so excuse the messy code.

Right now I'm using bootstrap columns along with a card to make the following

[PICTURE OF THE WEBSITE BECAUSE I DONT HAVE ENOUGH REPUTATION](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEofg.png)

The problem is that I cannot get the second row to move up close to the first row. not sure what kind of css element is useful in this situation. The element that i want moved up is the thing that is labled "thing" and "second row" in the code.

Anyways here is the code that is involved:

```
<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" id="test">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" style="overflow-y:auto">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">ORDER SUMMARY</h5>
        <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <!-- start content -->
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- FIRST ROW -->
        <!-- left column -->
        <div class="row" style="width: 100%">
            <div class="col-md-4" style = "width:0%; margin-right: 10%;"> ORDER DETAILS 
            <hr>  
             <!-- Order Number -->
                <div class="form-group" style = "margin-right: 10%;">
                  <label for="disabledTextInput">Disabled input</label>
                  <input type="text" id="disabledTextInput" class="form-control" placeholder="Disabled input" style= "display: inline">
                </div>
          </div>
          <!-- right column -->
          <div class="col-md-4" style="width:100%; margin-right:20%; height:20rem;" id = "order-summary"> ORDER SUMMARY
            <div class="card" style="width:17rem; height:24rem">
              <div class="card-body" style="width:100%" id="item-summary">                

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div> 
        <!-- SECOND ROW -->
        <div class = "row">
          <div class="col-md-4 ml-auto" style = "width:100%; margin-right: 20%; position:fixed;"> things   
            <hr>  
             <!-- Order Number -->
                <!-- <div class="form-group" style = "margin-right: 10%;">
                  <label for="disabledTextInput">Disabled input</label>
                  <input type="text" id="disabledTextInput" class="form-control" placeholder="Disabled input" style= "display: inline">
                </div>      
              -->
          </div> 
        </div> 


      </div>
```

CSS:

```
    .row {
    display: flex;
  }

  .col {
    flex: 50%;
  }

  @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .column {
      width: 100%;
    }
    .modal-content {
      width: 29rem;
      height: 38;
      margin: auto;
    }
  }
  label{
     font-weight: bold;
  }

  #create-order-modal {
    width: 750px !important;
    margin: auto !important;
  }

  .modal-content {
    width: 35rem;
    height: 35rem;
    margin: auto;
  } 
  .container-fluid{
    display:inline;
  }
```

I'M sure there is some sort of quick fix for my problem but i cant seem to find a solution. The first row element is too large for some reason, however i have not made any CSS elements that effect the size of the height.

Comment: I would start by removing the `position:fixed;` from the second row column...

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with the grid structure, and more importantly, you should use `d-flex flex-clolumn` and `flex-grow-1` instead of setting the height of the `elements`. If you want to change the width of the modal, change the width of `modal-dialog`.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Order Summary</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="container-fluid h-100">
          <div class="row h-100">
            <div class="col d-flex flex-column">
              <div class="w-100">
                <p>ORDER DETAILS </p>
                <hr>  
                <!-- Order Number -->
                <div class="form-group" >
                  <label for="disabledTextInput">Disabled input</label>
                  <input type="text" id="disabledTextInput" class="form-control" placeholder="Disabled input">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="mt-auto">
                <p>Things</p>
                <hr>  
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col d-flex flex-column">
              <p>Order Summary</p>
              <div class="card flex-grow-1" >
                <div class="card-body" id="item-summary">      
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos, corrupti asperiores nam possimus cum velit nemo sunt, atque voluptate natus, sed dolore praesentium nisi repellendus? Modi totam debitis facere voluptatem!</p>
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos, corrupti asperiores nam possimus cum velit nemo sunt, atque voluptate natus, sed dolore praesentium nisi repellendus? Modi totam debitis facere voluptatem!</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div> 
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QxzXoK

*I removed the `modal` from the outer `div` so that the modal be visible. You should add it if you use the code in your project.*

---

Comment if you have any question or in case of any issue in the code, I might answer.